# How to ignore comments when parsing xml in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml

Seems like this should be easy, but I'm not finding a simple configuration setting.  Basically I have a page that will be parsing xml files that may have some comment tags in them.  I'm loading it as an xml doc and looping through a particular node of the document and I'm running into problems because it's counting the comment as a child node.  Any way to tell asp.net not to look at comments other than writing my own check for `<!--` ?

Comment: How are you parsing the XML? Can you post the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use XmlNode, then that has a [NodeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.nodetype.aspx) property. Ignore the nodes where that has a value of "Comment".

An XNode has the same property.

Answer (score 0):

Use `XmlReaderSettings.IgnoreComments`:

```
XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
readerSettings.IgnoreComments = true;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("input.xml", readerSettings))
{
    XmlDocument myData = new XmlDocument();
    myData.Load(reader);
    // etc...
}
```